# SQL Server stored procedure / cursor

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I wanted to know if this is possible to do in SQL Server:

My table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE MEMBERSHIP
(
    Memebership_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,   
    MemberShip_Expiry_Date Datetime,
    Member_Account_Balance Money,
    Member_Blacklisted bit ,--(0 for no, 1 for yes)
    Customer_ID INT not null,
    Last_Payment datetime
)
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to use a stored procedure with or without a cursor inside of it to change the `Member_Blacklisted` column if the `Last_Payment` was more than 6 months from the date that has to be inserted e.g.

```
DECLARE @MemberID int,@Date datetime
```

My attempt so far:

```
DECLARE @MemberID int,@Date datetime

-- Declaring the Cursor. 
DECLARE C_Expired_Penalty_BlackList CURSOR
FOR
(
 SELECT 
 FROM MEMBERSHIP
)

-- Open the Cursor declared.
OPEN C_Expired_Penalty_BlackList
FETCH NEXT FROM C_Expired_Penalty_BlackList INTO @MemberID,@Date
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 IF @Date > DATEPART(MONTH,getdate()+6)
 BEGIN
  update MEMBERSHIP
  set Member_Blacklisted = 1
  Where Memebership_ID = @MemberID 
 END
  FETCH NEXT FROM C_Expired_Penalty_BlackList INTO @MemberID,@Date
END

CLOSE C_Expired_Penalty_BlackList
DEALLOCATE C_Expired_Penalty_BlackList
```

Comment: Check out beezir's answer. It will do what you want. Currently your date comparison is nonsensical because you're comparing a date to an int. When you do this you're comparing the number of days since January 1st, 1900 against a number between 1 and 12. You're comparison check will always be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE MEMBERSHIP 
SET Member_Blacklisted = 1 
WHERE Last_Payment < DATEADD(Month, -6, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I think using DatePart is a bad idea here as they can range anywhere from 6 to just under 7 months late, but considering that is the logic the OP was using this is right.

Comment: @Love2Learn Yeah, I just copied the logic from the question.  Changed it to use DATEADD instead.

Comment: Yeah, nice, I think the OP's logic is actually complete wrong because they're returning an int associated to the month six months in the future and comparing it against the Last_Payment which is really non-sensical. I think this is what they want.

Comment: Sorry if i sound dumb but what do you suggest must i change?

Comment: @user2363591 Use the above update in place of the entirety of the code you have in your post.

Comment: @user2363591 The command above will update any records that paid more than 6 months ago to be marked as blacklisted.  It replaces the entire stored procedure in your question.

Comment: Thank you Soooooo Much Guys!!!!!! I appreciate all The Help That seem to fix it :D